# Fetching data from the store in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have a getrank button which is supposed to make get request to the server

So for this i wrote a Getrank function in controller inside which i have this

```
var self = this;

this.store.find('post',"1").then(function(data){
    self.set('mydata',data);
    console.log(self.get('mydata'));
},
function(error){
    alert(error);
})
```

It returns a class.,instead i need a json to work on

Is it a normal behaviour or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is normal behavior.  Yes, you are doing something wrong.  I suggest reading over the Ember guides and learning how Ember works- http://emberjs.com/guides/.  Except in special cases, you don't normally deal with JSON- you are requesting a model object and getting one from the store.  If the store doesn't have one, it will fire an AJAX request and parse the response and put the object in the store.

Comment: so what are you suggesting...i should make  a  new route and hook  a model to it that gets the data from the server.Is there no way to call the store from the controller and get the model object.What if i dont want to create another route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a JSON response use jQuery's getJSON method.  Ember-Data gives you client side records that it manages with a plethora of additional functionality.

Ember and Ember Data are two different products and Ember works just fine without Ember-Data using POJOs